# flipbox react only to the actionbutton in shinydashboardPlus?

Tags: r, shinydashboard, box

I recently discovered flipbox, an excellent UI on shinydashboardPlus(version 2.0.0). I want to insert numericinput in the front, but every time I click the input, it flips. Is it possible to make the flip executed only on the actionbutton?

[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQCJt.jpg)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 12,
          uiOutput("active_side"), 
          actionButton("toggle", "Toggle flip box"),
          flipBox(
            id = "myflipbox", 
            trigger = "click",
            width = 12,
            front = div(
              class = "text-center",
              h1("Flip on click"),
              numericInput("obs", "Observations:", 10, min = 1, max = 100)
            ),
            back = div(
              class = "text-center",
              height = "300px",
              width = "100%",
              h1("Flip on hover"),
              p("More information....")
            )
          )
        )
    )
   )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$toggle, {
      updateFlipBox("myflipbox")
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: It seems to be a version issue of shinydashboardPlus. It was recently updated to version 2.0. https://rinterface.github.io/shinydashboardPlus/articles/improved-boxes.html

Comment: Hey there, 9 months later and I'm facing a similar situation. On the front side of my flip Box I've got an interactive plot, on the back some explanations. Did you find a way to flip the box only on the click of a button?